# How to replace the value in awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have the below file

```
cat log.txt

/root/logs/*.* {
    dbset
    quotatab
    rsyslog.conf 
    dataload 23
    server 25
    inputrc
}
```

I just want to replace the server vaule. here it is 25. but it can be anything. Using awk '/server/{print $NF}' log.txt can get the value and replace it using sed. but i want to do the get the value and replace in awk itself. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you could do it with awk itself  using awk's inbuilt sub or gsub function.

```
$ awk '/server/{sub(/.*/,"XX",$NF)}1' file
/root/logs/*_log {
dbset
quotatab
rsyslog.conf
dataload 23
server XX
inputrc
}
```

In the above i just replaced the $NF value `25` to `XX`. Change `XX` in the above sub function to another value according to your needs.

OR

```
awk '/server/{$NF="XX"}1' file
```

OR

You could use sed.

```
$ sed '/server/s/[^ ]* *$/XX/' file
/root/logs/*.* {
    dbset
    quotatab
    rsyslog.conf 
    dataload 23
    server XX
    inputrc
}
```

Comment: Seems easier to do `/server/{$NF="XX"}`

Comment: great! it works.. Thanks Avinash and William :)  When it does, line is displayed in the starting line instead of existing position. how can it be moved( tab or blank spaces before the line starts)

Comment: Thanks bunch :) one more question..if we use awk here, do you know how to add blank spaces in the particular line? For example, i want to add three blank spaces in the server line before it starts(no changes in the other lines)